# I CAN NOT GET THE RESULT I WANT

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float ort;
    int x,y;
    
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
    ort=(x+y)/2;
    printf("%d ve %d'nin ortalamasi : %.2f ",x,y,ort);
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote a program that calculates the average of 2 numbers entered, but it gives the wrong average.
For example i entered 2 and 3 it gave me 2.00 or i entered 4 and 5 it gave me 4.00

Comment: The types used in calculations in C is determined by the type of each operand. The type of the variable where the results are stored is irrelevant.

Comment: Try `ort=(x+y)/2.0f;` and less shouting please.

Comment: _"I CAN NOT GET THE RESULT I WANT"_ is pretty much why everyone is asking questions here. Try to be more specific when coming up with a good title.

Answer (score 3):

This is done using integer arithmetics:

```c
(x + y) / 2;
```

and `5 / 2` is `2` using integers. This integer `2` is then converted to `2.0f` when assigned to the `float` variable `ort`.

If you want to do floating arithmetics, convert the expression to a floating point expression.

In this case it's enough if you convert one operand to `float` and the second one will be implicitly converted to `float` when the `/` operator is used:

````````
    (x + y) / 2.0f;
//  ```````
//  implicitly converted to float
````````

... but to be extra clear, you could make both of them `float`:

```
(float)(x + y) / 2.0f;
```

Comment: It certainly doesn't matter for the types of sample data shown, but the OP probably wants to use `double` rather than `float` and the `%.2lf` format specifier.

Comment: @Chris _"OP probably wants..."_ - Could be. I usually use `double` myself and rarely use `float` or `long double`... Some graphic libraries are centered around `float` so then I use that of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a floating point number in your division to make sure that floating point division is applied:

```c
ort = (x + y) / 2.0;
```